# Page with posts from category doesn't work

Tags: page-template

I'm working on my wordpress site, and I want to have a page that shows all posts from the category 'portfolio' on a separate site. I'm using the following technique:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts

However, on my testblog this works fine ( http://dev.litso.com/portfolio-2/ ) but on my live blog it doesn't seem to load the custom pagetemplate portfolio.php ( http://www.stephanmuller.nl/portfolio-2/ ). Instead, it uses the regular page.php template.

Both are pages (not posts), use the exact same theme (not even a copy, the same physical theme in a multisite installation), the same custom field 'category' with a value of 'portfolio' and both blogs have at least one entry with the 'portfolio' category.

The only difference between the two is that the dev blog does *not* have the option to choose the page's template (yet it does use the custom Portfolio template). The live site does have this option and it's set to Portfolio of course but when I view the page it uses Page. I can't find out why this is either.

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, apparently I accidently copied the comment `Template Name: Portfolio` to my page.php as well, so when I selected the 'portfolio' template wordpress just picked page.php out of the two possible templates. May be a warning for other people that have this problem :)